# Scatter plot with labels instead of numbers on axis in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I would like to create a plot in R from a table like the following

Index Value
1      asdf
2      jkl
3      qwer
4      asdf

So I would like the string values on the x or y axis and the index value on the other axis.
If the axis have to be swapped that would be fine too. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is called a dotplot.

Comment: What data are you going to plot?

Answer (score 2):

Base graphics:

```
dotchart(dat$Index, dat$Value)
```

Lattice:

```
require(lattice)
 dotplot(Value ~ Index, data= dat)
```

(Notice that `lattice::dotplot` gave you two points on the same line while `dotchart` gave you two lines of "asdf".) If you want it to be vertical, dotplot has a horizontal argument you would set to FALSE.